# Git ignores credential.helper setting

Tags: git

For several months now, I've had to type in my credentials every time I want to push or pull from GitHub. I've tried several different credential helpers, but they all silently fail.

I believe I've found a clue as to why:

```
$ git config --add credential.helper fakecredentialhelper
$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/path/to/my/ssh_key': 
Already up to date.
```

According to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage), Git accepts any value for `credential.helper` and attempts to run that program. But `fakecredentialhelper` doesn't exist, meaning Git should get this result:

```
$ git credential-fakecredentialhelper --file=/mnt/shared/creds get
git: 'credential-fakecredentialhelper' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

But calling `git pull` succeeds without complaint, meaning that Git didn't even attempt to run it. I'm entering my credentials; why is Git skipping `credential.helper`?

Or is Git swallowing the error?

<sup>Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS</sup>
<sup>Git 2.17.1</sup>

Comment: The underlying problem (Git not working with Seahorse) seems to have gone away now that I've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 and Git 2.19.1. I still can't make it use `fakecredentialhelper`, but maybe it's just swallowing the error. Does Git swallow errors?

Comment: Did you try:
`git help -a | grep credential-`